# geometric median for rigid body

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mathematical-optimization, rigid-bodies

I need to implement a "geometric median"-type algorithm that would apply to rigid bodies, meaning it would not only find a point minimizing the distance from a set of points, but would also take into account the orientation of the body.  I haven't found a solution for this type of problem anywhere, while for the geometric median (or Weber or Fermat-Torricelli problem, or facilities location problem), there is a lot of information available, including the Weiszfeld algorithm (and modern improvements).  I'm hoping someone will have references to possible solutions.  I would have thought this to be a relatively common problem in registration, but maybe I just haven't found the right words to search for...

My problem could be formulated as follows: Say I have a "reference" rigid body with 3 non-colinear points (a triangle), and I measure the coordinates of the 3 points a bunch of times (with some error, or the object was moving a bit).  I want to find a good "central location", that would minimize the sum of distances (not square distances) between each measured point and its corresponding centrally-located-object point.  This is equivalent to the "multi-facility location problem" but with extra contstraints of fixed distances between the "facilities" and with each point pre-assigned to a facility (not necessarily the closest one).

Actually, I'm thinking instead of minimizing the sum for all the points, I'd only keep the max distance out of the 3 points for each measurement. (is that what's called "minimax"?)  But I don't think that would make a big difference in the type of algorithm I'd have to use.

A possible difficulty compared to the geometric median could be that with the added freedom of rotations, the quantity to minimize is no longer convex (not 100% sure, but I think).  I'm hoping I can still use a similar algorithm as Weiszfeld's (which is a subgradient method), and hopefully this has been investigated previously.  Thanks for any help!

P.S. I'll be doing this in Matlab.

Comment: I don't know if this may help, but could you take a look inside the book "Graphics Gems IV"?, there is a gem (Chapter I, section 1, page 3) named "Centroid of a Polygon", the authors describes a way to find the mass center of the polygon using basic mechanics. 

If you can't access the book in physical, check it online in google books

Comment: Thanks, that is quite a different problem though (least squares and no rotation involved).  I can think of a simple enough way to calculate this directly, no need for an iterative optimization algorithm.  To clarify, I'm not looking for one point inside a body, but a central location and orientation of a body compared to many other copies of itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any research on this subject. The first thing I would do is to use Weiszfeld's algorithm without rigidity constraints to find geometric medians of individual points, define lagrange multipliers corresponding to deviations of edges of the object from expected values, and use gradient descent to find a constrained local minimum. I can't prove that it will always work, but, intuitively, it should as long as deviations are sufficiently small.

Comment: If you do the second part numerically (I think that you'll have to), keep in mind this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Example:_numerical_optimization

Comment: Thanks, I had come across this (Lagrange multiplier wiki) this week.  Good thing to keep in mind if I go that way.